# Build iOS Adhoc & Distrib Release via command line (xcrun) not working anymore (err ERROR ITMS-9000)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, ad-hoc-distribution, xcrun

I use to automate the build of my Adhoc and Distrib release of my apps with a simple script:

> ```
> echo "***** xcodebuild: compile project"
> xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -sdk "${TARGET_SDK}" -configuration Release CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="${PROJECT_BUILDDIR}"
>
> echo "***** xcrun Package app (ipa file) - Adhoc release"
> /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication "${PROJECT_BUILDDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.app" -o
> ```
>
> "${PROJECT_BUILDDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}_adhoc.ipa" --sign
>   "${DEVELOPPER_NAME}" --embed "${ADHOC_PROVISONNING_PROFILE}"
>       echo "***** xcrun Package app (ipa file) - AppStore release"
>       /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication "${PROJECT_BUILDDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.app" -o
>   "${PROJECT_BUILDDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}_appstore.ipa" --sign
>   "${DEVELOPPER_NAME}" --embed "${APPSTORE_PROVISONNING_PROFILE}"

It was working fine before. But then I installed Mac OS Maverik and I also updated my expired certificates & prov profiles. And since then, when I try to upload the generated IPA to iTunes Connect (for the Distribution release) or TestFlight (for the Adhoc release), I get this error message:

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Code Signing. The executable
>   'Payload/mosa_en_it.app/mosa_en_it' must be signed with the
>   certificate that is contained in the provisioning profile." at
>   SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

But it's working when I do it manually on XCode (Archive->Distribute..).

Also, I don't know if it's related but I have lots of duplicates certificates: [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ppoo60d059x1vrw/Screenshot%202014-02-24%2010.49.51.png)
 (but I don't know how to delete them)

Thanks in advance for your help